# After adding the play sound action when clicking does not play sound - flutter flow

Tags: flutter, audio, flutterflow

I have a problem like in the description.

Namely after adding an action in the flutter flow "Play sound" when clicked the sound doesn't play, could I have done something wrong or is it a flutter flow error?[photo of a set action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8mlo.png)

Comment: Without your code, how can we help you?

Comment: Please debug this buy adding play sound on another screen , under another Action type, such as page load and see if it works?